# Spring JPA derived queries when entity has getter for associated entity id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
public class Post{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}


@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Post> posts= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

there is also a repository

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
  List<Post> findAllByUserId(Long id);
}
```

it all works. But when I need to get the id Post.user.id and I add a method to the class Post

```
public Long getUserId(){
        return user== null ? null : user.getId();
    }
```

then the method findAllByUserId stops working (IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name UserId).
Is there a way to overcome this error? Or is there a more convenient method to get the ID of a related entity?

1. I tried putting an annotation @Transient on the method getUserId, it didn't help
2. I know I can use a method findAllByUser(User user), but I'm interested in getting an entity by id
3. I know I can use @Query but that would be too verbose
4. the only way I found is to rename the method, for example call it _getUserId, but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to get the posts made by a user (given a user id). Hence the statement

> 2. I know I can use a method findAllByUser(User user), but I'm interested
>    in getting an entity by id

I suggest you remove the method `getUserId()` from `Post`.

`List<Post> findAllByUserId(Long id);` will still work despite not having the method `getUserId()` in `Post`.

You can also rename it to `List<Post> findAllByUser_Id(Long id);` as well, to highlight that the `Id` is from the entity `User`.

For more info on how spring does it, best to refer to the [spring data jpa's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

Comment: I would like to have a convenient way to get the ID of a related entity. Now the `getUserId` method is the most convenient.
There's another way
```@Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;```
but in this case there will be a duplication of the column user_id

Comment: `List<Post> findAllByUser_Id(Long id);` - works, but it looks worse than `_getUserId()`